# Attempting to call method in collection from view in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

Im just starting to us backbone.js and following some simple tutorials, though i have hit a bump in the road. I cant seem to get the FriendCollection.add method to run. I dont get any errors. Is there something im missing? I believe it has something to do with this.FriendCollection.add(friend_model).

```
var Friend = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var FriendCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend
({
    initalize: function(models,options)
    {
        this.bind("add", options.view.addFriendLi);
    }
});

var FriendModel = Backbone.Model.extend
({
    name:null
});

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend
({
    el:$("body"),

    initialize: function()
    {
        this.FriendCollection = new FriendCollection(null,{view:this});
    },

    events:
    {
        "click #add-friend":"showPrompt",
    },

    showPrompt: function()
    {
        var friend_name = prompt("Who is your friend?");
        var friend_model = new FriendModel({name:friend_name});
        this.FriendCollection.add(friend_model);
    },

    addFriendLi: function(model)
    {
        $("#friends-list").append("<li>"+model.get('name') + "</li>");
    },
});

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var appview = new AppView;
});
```

Comment: [I think it should be `on` not `bind`.](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-add)

Comment: Nothing change, still did trigger the method "add"

Comment: @asawyer: `bind` has been deprecated in favor of `on` (to better match jQuery's names AFAIK) but `bind` is still supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled `initialize` in `FriendCollection`, so you're never actually binding the collection to the passed in view.

```
var FriendCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend
({
    initialize: function(models,options) // Fixed here
    {
        this.bind("add", options.view.addFriendLi);
    }
});
```